# NavBar elements are not coming in single line even if i am using bootstrap to that

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>OmniFood</title>
      <!--Google fonts-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,400,900|Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

      <!--CSS Stylesheets-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/style.css">

      <!--Font Awesome-->
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/29ae7bcec9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <!--bootstrap scripts-->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    </head>

      <body>
        <section >
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <nav class="navbar">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link"href="#">FOOD DELIVERY</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link"href="#">HOW IT WORKS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link"href="#">OUR CITIES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link"href="#">SIGN UP</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            </div>




      </body>
    </html>
```

so my code is working but it is not coming in a single line which is supposed be want my nav bar elements on right in a single line but they are coming line by line
i tried to do it in css using display inline-block but still not working out

Answer (score 0):

Add class  `flex-row` on `<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto flex-row">`

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine, as its responsive so i think you are using small devices thats why its in block if you still need in a row add class `flex-row` with `navbar-nav`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>OmniFood</title>
      <!--Google fonts-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,400,900|Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

      <!--CSS Stylesheets-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/style.css">

      <!--Font Awesome-->
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/29ae7bcec9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <!--bootstrap scripts-->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    </head>

      <body>
        <section >
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link"href="#">FOOD DELIVERY</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link"href="#">HOW IT WORKS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link"href="#">OUR CITIES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link"href="#">SIGN UP</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            </div>


</section >

      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add style for list 'display:inline-block' also add CSS for '.navbar-nav{display:inline-block !important}'.

```css
.navbar-nav{display:inline-block !important;}
li.nav-item {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,400,900|Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

      <!--CSS Stylesheets-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/style.css">

      <!--Font Awesome-->
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/29ae7bcec9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <!--bootstrap scripts-->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <nav class="navbar">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link"href="#">FOOD DELIVERY</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link"href="#">HOW IT WORKS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link"href="#">OUR CITIES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link"href="#">SIGN UP</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            </div>
```